# не могу приобрести собственную программу. "Издатель не может купить этот товар"

Tags: android

Собственно вот. сам написал, сам не могу юзать премиальную версию. как быть? отдельно компиллить без проверки покупок - затратно и неудобно.

Answer (score 3):

Создай тестовый аккаунт и добавь в список тестировщиков

> To test your In-app Billing implementation with actual in-app
>   purchases, you will need to register at least one test account on the
>   Google Play Developer Console. You cannot use your developer account
>   to test the complete in-app purchase process because Google payments
>   does not let you buy items from yourself. If you have not set up test
>   accounts before, see Setting up test accounts.

Comment: Тестовый есть, но с плея устанавливается с первичного аккаунта. Удалять постоянный тоже не вариант. Неужели более простого решения нет?

Comment: Нет. To test your In-app Billing implementation with actual in-app purchases, you will need to register at least one test account on the Google Play Developer Console. You cannot use your developer account to test the complete in-app purchase process because Google payments does not let you buy items from yourself. If you have not set up test accounts before, see Setting up test accounts.
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static